# Is there an idiom or set phrase for "all you need to do is just doing it"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Usually, in order to do something, we need to be well-prepared for it. For example, if you want to cook a dinner, you have to go to the market, choose fresh food, bring it home, season it. After that, you are now ready to cook. So, if you have someone else done all that stuff for you, then your only job now is just cooking. Is there an idiom or set phrase for this? I think just saying "just cook" is so simple.

My initial intention is to use it for cooking only, but general idioms are welcomed.

Comment: @AlanCarmack well, *just do it* is more about motivation, not err to the side of "everything is ready to do it"

Comment: Regarding your objection to "just cook" - it's simple, granted, but it works.

Comment: [Just do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXsQAXx_ao0)

Comment: Thank Goodness there isn't and I'm sorry to point this out but if you first corrected everything else in that question, the query would as like as not vanish…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin why does not having one is fortunate? How should I correct the question, and what do you mean by saying "the query would as like as not vanish"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have edited *just cook* to *just cooking*. Is there any other thing that you would suggest?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't know if you were making a point, but your second comment which starts with *Change...* is chockablock full of typos and grammatical errors. Ooker I would change  `I'm intent to` to *“I only intend  to use it for cooking, but I also welcome...”* OR **It is my intention to use it for .... only....*

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A Thanks; I musta bin tireder’n I thunk. Change ‘why does not having one is fortunate’ back to ’Thank Goodness there isn't’ then look at the difference. 

Even Microsoft’s spelling and grammar checkers might make the odd improvement and your search engine should find many flexible e-tools eager to help

‘The query would as like as not vanish means that if you correct at least half the errors hiding in there, the rest might become clear.

You might for instance be ‘… intent on using it… ‘ or ‘… intending to use it… ’ but neither is the same as ‘I’m intent to…’

Comment: Nothing before ‘… you are now ready to cook…’ is wrong neither is any of it necessary.

You might get away with ‘… your only job now is cooking…’ or ‘… to cook’ or ‘… just to cook’ but never ‘… is just cook’ nor ‘… just cook’ however simple that looks. Change the context to ‘What is your job?’ and search some conjugation sites:

Comment: @Ooker Well done and you meant ‘Is there anything else (that) you would suggest?’

Sorry I didn’t even notice before and there are two wholly different topics here. 

The second is the meaning and structure of the example, which certainly blinded me, for one…

The first is that the only idiom which might fit your bill is the simplest, ‘…to cook.’

… …

Comment: Still in the title, ‘all you need (to) do is just do it’ or ‘just doing it is all you need (to) do’ both work better.

Comment: Meanwhile, back at the text: Usually, in order to do something, you need to be well-prepared for it. For example, if you want to cook a dinner, you have to go to the market, choose fresh food, bring it home and season it. After that, you are ready to cook. So, if you had someone else do all that stuff for you, then your only job now is to cook. 
Is there an idiom or set phrase for this? I think  "just cook" is so simple. (Did you mean ‘so…’ or perhaps ‘^ simple’?
My initial intention is to use it for cooking only, but general idioms are welcome.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin what's the difference between *all you need to do is just doing it* and *just doing is is all you need to do*?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Perhaps I'm trying to be too subtle and we should ignore that one.

Answer (score 0):

These terms are cooking specific, but I think the distinction you are looking for is *meal planning* vs *meal prep*.

*Meal planning* is figuring out the ingredient list and purchasing all necessary ingredients.

*Meal prep* is measuring/chopping/preparing the ingredients, then cooking/mixing/making the dishes. These might be done at the same time, or you might prep your ingredients (measure/chop/chill/marinade) some time before the final cooking.

Anything more specific would depend on the specific dish/recipe (mix then bake, or marinade then grill, or whatever).