# What is the name of the amount of food that is ready to be cooked for a meal?

Tags: single-word-requests, food

A meal is the amount of food that is ready to be eaten on regular occasions. What is the name of such amount of food that is ready to be cooked, one step before it is actually a meal? According to the Oxford Dictionary:

> - **Meal**: the food **eaten** on regular occasions.
> - **Ingredient**: any of the foods or substances that are combined to make **a particular dish**.
> - **Foodstuff**: a substance suitable for consumption as food.

Since *meal* is directly eatable, it's imply that the food is cooked. *Ingredient* is the food to make a particular dish, not a whole meal; a meal can have a couple dishes. *Foodstuff* or *food* aren't imply anything about the cooking process.

If there is no word that satisfies completely, which of these words can be a good substitution? I guess it's *meal*, but I'm not sure.

A related question from mine: [Is there an idiom or set phrase for “all you need to do is just cook it”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/358222/80007)

Comment: May I ask where you got that definition? A meal can be any portion of food - cooked or not - that is to be eaten on regular occasion.

Comment: how about *Ingredients?*

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meal as opposed to your "A meal is a portion of food that is cooked."

Comment: @AndrewL please see my update

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary please see my update

Comment: @Keepthesemind thanks. I was careless of my words. I have updated the question

Comment: Consider foodstuff(s) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foodstuff or simply food

Comment: @Keepthesemind they aren't imply about the cooking process

Comment: I don't believe there is such a word. You would have to say "the ingredients for the meal" or something.

Comment: The word "prepped" is used in restaurants to refer to the stage(s) prior to serving or cooking. The chef may say to the members of his kitchen brigade, "Make sure we have enough prepped starters for the large table of 10 diners".

Comment: The range of answers here suggests that the question is not clear at all. Perhaps you could post a picture of what you mean.

Comment: Kate seems to have killed it… and whether it's a meal has nothing at all to do with regularity, frequency or even time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to ask this kind of question on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange site for cooks.

The way to describe all the ingredients, in the state of having been purchased, cleaned, trimmed, cut, etc., is to say that they have been *prepped* (short for prepared).

A person in a restaurant kitchen that does nothing but clean, trim, etc is called a *prep cook*, and they work at a *prep station*.  When working with a chef, one might say:

> Do you need me to prep the vegetables?

Answer (score 0):

Ingredients

When you reference a meal "ingredients" can also mean all of the food required for a complete meal/occasion.

For example:

1. I want to make Thanksgiving dinner but I'm missing some ingredients. I still need to buy a turkey, potatoes, and cranberries.
2. Can you shop for the brunch ingredients? There's a list on the counter.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what others think, but I wouldn't class a turkey as 'an ingredient' unless I was going to butcher it to make it into a pie or curry or something. Chambers Dictionary agrees with that, defining an ingredient as something that is put into a mixture or compound. So turkey is an ingredient in turkey pie but not in 'roast turkey'.

Comment: You don't use turkey in your roast turkey? What's wrong with you?! (okay, but seriously, you *do* form a compound when you add salt, say, so that's not the best example of your point.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a meal which is prepared **by someone else** and simply requires cooking to become a meal, then that's a [***ready-meal***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ready_meal):

> *British* 
>   A meal sold in a pre-cooked form that only requires reheating.
>
> > All they sell is frozen ready meals, but they're prepared fresh each day and the name of the chef is on the packet.
> >
> > The main ingredients for the ready meals — free-range chicken, outdoor reared pork and lamb and beef raised on organic farmland — come from Yorkshire farms.
>
> [ODO]

If you are referring to a meal you have prepared and simply put in the freezer to be ready for another day, then that's usually just a *meal* which you're going to cook. While it may fit the basic description of a ready-meal, you have prepared it. A ready-meal implies that you bought the food ready to cook and that's all your  involvement is.